# Using AI Azure Video indexer I am getting URL_UNREACHABLE but the URL is accessible from other sites

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure

I have implemented an integration with Azure AU Indexer. The POST call for index returns URL_UNREACHABLE but the URL is accessible from a web browser for example. No authentication is defined yet on the download server.

```
 org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request: "{"ErrorType":"URL_UNREACHABLE","Message":"Url 'https://server/api/v1/download/3911ed0c-16eb-4ad8-a282-244006f05346' is unreachable. Trace id: '06e23f6f-d3d7-4bd1-a750-51877b30e8e9'."}"
```

I am using Java SpringBoot to server the request with this piece of code

```java
@GetMapping("download/{uuid}")
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> download(@PathVariable String uuid) throws Exception {

    DownloadResult result = teService.download(uuid);

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + uuid + "\"")
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, result.getObjectSize().toString())
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, result.getMimeType())
            .header(HttpHeaders.PRAGMA, "public")
            .header(HttpHeaders.EXPIRES, "-1")
            .header(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL, "public, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0")
            .body(result.getResponseBody());
}
```

I have tried to change the Headers to return it as an inline stream with no success. I am expecting that the Azure AI indexer can download the video as other sites

Answer (score 0):

- Check if the URL is accessible from the same network as the Azure Video Indexer service. You can try accessing the URL from a different machine on the same network to see if it is accessible.
- It is possible that the URL is blocked by a firewall or network restriction that prevents access from certain IP addresses or networks. Make sure that the IP address of the server running the indexer is allowed to access the URL.
- I have installed Azure Video Indexer and locally I have recorded a video to index the file and download.
  [image]

[image]

- Below Spring Boot controller that uses the Azure Video Indexer SDK to index videos and retrieve video data.

```java
@RestController
public class VideoController {
    private static final String FILE_DIRECTORY = "/path/to/videos/";

    @Autowired
    private AzureVideoIndexerService videoIndexerService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/download/{uuid}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> downloadVideo(@PathVariable String uuid) {
        try {
            File file = new File(FILE_DIRECTORY + uuid + ".mp4");
            byte[] videoBytes = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
            headers.setContentLength(videoBytes.length);
            headers.setContentDisposition(ContentDisposition.attachment()
                .filename(uuid + ".mp4")
                .build());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(videoBytes, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/index/{uuid}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> indexVideo(@PathVariable String uuid) {
        try {
            String videoUrl = "http://localhost:8080/download/" + uuid;
            String indexId = videoIndexerService.indexVideo(videoUrl);
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Video indexing started with index id " + indexId, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Failed to start video indexing: " + e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

The .mp4 file that has been indexed into Azure AI Indexer.

[image]

The `uuid` parameter in the `downloadVideo` method corresponds to the UUID or File ID of the video file that you want to download. Below is the sample URL which makings as the request to download the file.

[image]

- Azure Video indexer might be running in a different network environment than the one you are using to access the URL. That may result in different network configurations, firewalls, proxies etc., that might be blocking access to the URL from the Azure Video indexer.